# PHP Calculate total document saves per day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the total document saves per day. But i don't have any idea how.
Here are the Columns along with their data in my Database.

```
report_id    doc_date   total_doc 
- 1          2017-06-06  1  
- 2          2017-06-23  1  
- 3          2017-06-14  1  
- 4          2017-06-12  1  
- 5          2017-06-16  1
- 6          2017-06-21  1
- 7          2017-06-14  1
- 9          2017-06-13  1
- 10         2017-06-21  1
- 11         2017-06-12  1
- 12         2017-06-18  1
- 13         2017-06-12  1
.....
```

Above, there are similar date, for example,

```
- 3          2017-06-14  1
- 7          2017-06-14  1
```

I need a sql query which would calculate and show the total document saves per day. So for 14 of June 2017, the total would be 2.
Any idea guys?
FYI the total_doc is automatically equal to 1.
**Updated:**
And show the total document saves in that day.

Comment: Have you ever tried anything?

Comment: Yes, But i got always error i'm not a pro in the field of mysql.

Comment: Then post your query and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    doc_date,
    count(doc_date) AS saves
FROM documents
GROUP BY doc_date
ORDER BY doc_date ASC;
```

OR

```
SELECT
    doc_date,
    sum(total_doc) AS saves
FROM documents
GROUP BY doc_date
ORDER BY doc_date ASC;
```

**Notices:**

1) If you are using the first option, then you can remove the column `total_doc`. That would also be my advice. You have a good mysql format of the date values in the `doc_date` column, so you can make solid operations on it.

2) You can sort the records in a descending order by `doc_date`, if you wish.

3) Don't forget to alias (like I did with `AS saves`) the columns when using functions like `count` or `sum`. Because then you can use a `HAVING` filter also. So something like this - all documents with more than one save per day:

```
SELECT 
    doc_date,
    count(doc_date) AS saves
FROM documents
GROUP BY doc_date
HAVING saves > 1
ORDER BY doc_date ASC;
```

And then you can also filter by only one saved document on a specified day:

```
SELECT 
    doc_date,
    count(doc_date) AS saves
FROM documents
WHERE doc_date = "2017-06-12"
GROUP BY doc_date
HAVING saves > 1
ORDER BY doc_date ASC;
```

4) Or you can also just ignore `HAVING` and `doc_date` if you wish. That would give you the documents saved on a specified day.

```
SELECT count(doc_date) AS saves
FROM documents
WHERE doc_date = "2017-06-12"
GROUP BY doc_date
ORDER BY doc_date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (set `table_name` to the name of your table):

```
SET @row_count = 0;
SELECT (@row_count:=@row_count+1) AS totalSaves FROM table_name WHERE doc_date='2017-06-14'
```

The first line defines a variable, `row_count`, and sets it to `0`.

The second line goes through the database, finds all rows where the date is `2017-06-14`, and for each one increments `row_count`.

Then, we `SELECT` the final number stored in `row_count` as a single row in a column labeled as `totalSaves`.

Set `table_name` to the name of your table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_date, sum(total_doc) AS total 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY doc_date
```

Change table_name with your table name.

If you just want show 1 date :

```
SELECT doc_date, sum(total_doc) AS total 
FROM table_name
WHERE doc_date = '2017-06-14'
GROUP BY doc_date
```